# Html - Random <p></p> tags appearing on Web page but not in Source Code

Tags: html

Essentially, I'm making a tier-based pricing grid and it needs to look like this:

[image: Correct Design]

However, when my code is placed onto the web page (through Wordpress) 
a random set of

tags are above the '10+ Sessions" pricing box, which messes up the spacing. The

tag has a 20px top padding.

It looks like this:

[image: Bug]

So, I inspected the element and found that there's a set of

tags above the box with a top padding of 20px.

```
<div class="rpt_plan  rpt_plan_ori rpt_plan_3  " style="
margin-left: 0px;
width: 565px;
margin-top: 0px;
"><p></p>
<div class="rpt_title rpt_title_3">10+ Sessions</div>
<div class="rpt_head rpt_head_3" style="
height: 152px;
"><p></p>
<div class="rpt_recurrence rpt_recurrence_3">Per Hour</div>
<div class="rpt_price rpt_price_3"><span 
class="rpt_currency">£</span>20</div>
</div>
<p><a target="_self" href="#" style="background: rgb(243, 167, 
6);cursor: pointer;height: 45px;" class="rpt_foot rpt_foot_3 pum-
trigger">Sign Up</a></p>
</div>
```

The

tags after the opening of the div is the problem.

However, the tags aren't there in the original source code, which is this:

```
<div class="rpt_plan  rpt_plan_ori rpt_plan_3  " style="
margin-left: 0px;
width: 565px;
margin-top: 0px;
">
<div class="rpt_title rpt_title_3">10+ Sessions</div>
<div class="rpt_head rpt_head_3" style="
height: 152px;
">
<div class="rpt_recurrence rpt_recurrence_3">Per Hour</div>
<div class="rpt_price rpt_price_3"><span 
class="rpt_currency">£</span>20</div>
</div>
<p><a target="_self" href="#" style="background: rgb(243, 167, 
6);cursor: pointer;height: 45px;" class="rpt_foot rpt_foot_3 pum-
trigger">Sign Up</a></p></div>
```

I just can't figure out why the

tags are there.

Could anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem — http://jsbin.com/regumugago/1/edit?html,output — try providing a real [mcve]

Comment: I said a [mcve]. That doesn't look minimal. Also edit your question instead of linking to a third party site. Preferably [as a live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar problem, install a plugin called Raw HTML for Wordpress. This prevents Wordpress from attempting to format your Raw HTML and adding random paragraph tags.